# Discrepancy between LOGEST and chart exponential trend line parameters

Tags: google-sheets

This question is tagged under “google-sheets”.

The Google Sheets function LOGEST takes two datasets then displays two or more parameters, dependent on certain flags, for the best fit ideal exponential growth curve. The best fit equation would be in this format: y = b*m^x, where m and b would be the two parameters returned by this function.

Using Google Sheets chart and editing it with the following steps: Customize, Series, Trendline, Exponential Type, Use Equation Label, can provide a fit in this format: y = d*e^(s*x). Comparing this format with the format of LOGEST, parameter d here would be like parameter b in LOGEST, and e^s is like m. However, although d and e^s is close to b and m, they are different. For example, b = 5.421 and m = 1.235, while d = 5.12 and e^s = 1.249.

The chart shown below was created from a dataset, which is also listed below the chart. The dark blue line is based off of the actual data. While the light blue line is the trend line for the best fit exponential growth curve (y = 5.12e^0.222x) and the red line (y = 5.421*1.235^x) is based off the y-values calculated with the parameters provided by LOGEST. Although the light blue line trends closer to the dark blue line than the red line does at x-values higher than 8 in this case, if one of the two lines, either light blue or red, is displayed at one time, then the two resulting charts wouldn’t appear visually different to the viewer.

However, when these two pairs of parameters are used for predictions, such as for x = 11, y = 55.24 using LOGEST parameters, and y = 58.86 using trend line parameters. The difference of these two numbers can be significant depending on the context.

Would either of these parameter pairs, one from LOGEST and one from trend line, be better than the other in general, or only in some specific cases?

[Example Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkDCN.png)
￼

data_Y  data_X

7,       1.1

8.9,        2

10.56,      3.2

12.33,      4

14,       4.9

15.9,        5.1

18.4,        6

23.7,        7.2

38.66,        8.8

(As a comparison, both LINEST and chart linear trend line gave the same parameters.)

Performed an Internet search about this discrepancy between LOGEST and chart exponential trend line parameters and located a similar question (unanswered) at https://support.google.com/docs/thread/33754284/discrepancy-between-logest-parameters-returned-and-chart-exponential-trendline-results?hl=en.

In order to obtain the parameter values from the trend line, go to chart editor, customize, series tab, check the trendline option then set the label to “Use Equation” to display the equation of the best fit trend line. Refer to the link above to see the provided chart where the caption shows the equation of the best fit trend line as “data_Y = 5.12e^0.222x”.

Comment: `Would either of these parameter pairs, one from LOGEST and one from trend line, be better than the other in general, or only in some specific cases?` Is this a question about programming in Google sheets, or a question about your data?